# UICollectionViewCell with IBOutlets and segues

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue, uicollectionviewcell

I've created a custom UICollectionViewCell that has several buttons and labels within it. I need each button to bring up a different view via popover. I tried putting segues on the buttons and that gave me compiler errors.

```
".../MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard: Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x4012ea380  <IBProxyObject: 0x4012d7600> => anchorView => <IBUICollectionViewCell: 0x4012d06a0>>"
```

I tried putting the segue on the prototype cell itself, same result. I removed all of the IBOutlets from the buttons and labels, still get compiler errors.

How does one properly set up a collection view cell to outlets and segues? I've seen tutorials that do this very thing but it's simply not working.

TIA!

Janene

Comment: Please show some code about popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me. I wanted each collection view cell to have a button that would bring up a popup.

First, in Interface Builder, I created a new view controller in my storyboard - this view controller is the destination popover when the user touches the button. In IB, make sure to give this view controller a Storyboard ID in the Identity Inspector, I used "destinationView." In the Attributes Inspector, I set the Size to "Form Sheet" and set Presentation to "Form Sheet."

I dropped the button onto my collection view cell in my collection view on the source view controller.

In my source view controller, I created a method to handle the button:

```
- (IBAction)handleButton:(id)sender
```

Then I hooked that button action up to that method in the source view controller in Interface Builder.

The code for this function looked like:

```
- (IBAction)handleButton:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    // get an instance of the destination view controller 
    // you can set any info that needs to be passed here 
    // just use the "sender" variable to find out what view/button was touched
    DestinationViewController *destVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destinationView"]; 

    // create a navigation controller (so we can have buttons and a title on the title bar of the popover) 
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:destVC];

    // say that we want to present it modally 
    [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    // show the popover 
    [[self navigationController] presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{

    }]; 
}
```

In my destination view controller, I added a title, and a Done button for dismissing the popover:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissExampleButton:)];

    self.title = @"Example Title";
}

- (IBAction)dismissExampleButton:(id)sender
{
    [[self parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }]; 
}
```

Note that I tried to use segues instead. However, the popup did not work for me, it merely animated to a new full size destination view controller, even though the setting in IB was "Form Sheet." I set up the destination view controller in IB as above, and created a segue from the source view controller to the destination view controller. I gave the segue an Identifier in the Attributes Inspector, like "exampleSegue". And I hooked my button up to the action in the source view controller.

With this way, the source view controller looked like:

```
- (IBAction)handleButton:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"exampleSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

And, to get data to the destination view controller, I also implemented this in the source view controller:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"exampleSegue"]) {

        DestinationViewController *destViewController = (DestinationViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        // give the destViewController additional info here
        // destViewController.title.text = @"blah"; 
        // etc. 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I guess this is the key: "created a segue from the source view controller to the destination view controller." When I try to create the segue directly from the prototype custom cell, it won't compile.